# Elasticsearch Sort based on value first

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, elasticsearch

I want to sort results on the `release date`. I want `2015` movies first and the rest of the years sorted on the `has_poster` value. So I get results like:

```
2015, 2015, 1989, 2017, 2006
```

etc.

So far this is what I've got.

```
$params['index'] = 'movies';
$params['type']  = 'movie';
$params['body']['size'] = 50;
$params['body']['sort'] = array(
    array('has_poster'  => "desc"),
    array('_score'  => "desc"),
);        
$params['body']['query']['filtered'] = array(
    'query' => array(
        'query_string' => array(
            'query' => "survivor",
            'fields' => array('name', 'orig_title'),
            'default_operator' => "AND"
        ),
    )
);
```

I need the equivalent of `... ORDER BY FIELD(releasedate, 2015), has_poster DESC ...` in MySQL for Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a scripted sorting:

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "script": "if(doc['releasedate'].date.year==2015) return 1; else return 0;",
        "type": "number",
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "has_poster": "desc"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I just tried this one but I get a BadRequest400Exception error in PHP (laravel). If I comment out the `_script` part then I get results again.

Comment: `ScriptException[scripts of type [inline], operation [search] and lang [groovy] are disabled]; }]` you need to enable dynamic scripting in Elasticsearch.

Comment: Oh. I'll try that and will let you know if it worked. Thanks!

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting

Comment: But I need to make you aware of https://www.elastic.co/blog/running-groovy-scripts-without-dynamic-scripting and suggest putting the script on file, instead. But, until then, see the script itself works for you.

Comment: And yes! It works. Thanks @Andrei. I'll look into the links you've provided. :)

Answer (score 0):

Im not work    =>type name is string

```
$params['body']['sort']= array('name' => 'desc' );
```

**or**

```
$params=[
                'index'=>'pets',
                'type'=>'bird',
                'body'=>[
                    'query'=>[
                        'bool'=>[
                            'must'=>[],
                            'filter'=>[
                                'range'=>[
                                    'registered'=>[
                                    'gte' => "2020-10-01", 
                                    'lte' => "2020-11-30"]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    'sort'=>[
                        'name'=>[
                            'order'=>'asc'
                        ]
                    ]
                    
                ]
            ];
```

but not work